# How to configure phpStorm (with XAMPP and Xdebug) to display/render the web page in the browser when In RUN it

Tags: xampp, phpstorm

**GOAL**: I'm trying to view the .php page I've edited and "run" the php page. 
FYI to avoid conflicts with Skype, I reset the port for XAMPP from 80 to 8080

**UPDATED: SYMPTOMS**

When I click on RUN I just get the html/php of the page displayed with "result 0"

If i manually browse to the page (//localhost:8080//phpStorm/php_test.php)  it runs correctly on the server displaying correctly in the browser.
If I Debug that works correctly too (I had to install Xdebug and configure the php ) (lthough it doesn't automatically display and render the page in the browser.

**If I Run the page then it does not load the browser.**

I installed xampp (although had to set it to use port 8080 b/c of a port conflict) and it works fine.
BUT I can't figure out what configuration to use in phpStorm.

Here's a [Screencast of the problem](http://screencast.com/t/6KQcCiSTgCP)

**WHAT I TRIED**
I followed the instructions at the page below and it still doesn't work. I get the same results as above or (if I modify the configuration) phpStorm launches the browser and tries to display my .php page as if it were in the httdoc\ directory. (The Help file made it seem like phpStorm was supposed to copy the file to that directory, but it's not.
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE

Comment: 1) No, PhpStorm does not have built-in interpreter (since everyone needs different sets of plugins/diff version etc) -- it only has simple built-in HTTP server 2) *"displayed with "result 0""* screenshot of your Run/Debug Config please. Sounds like you have not read documentation properly and created configuration of **wrong** type (most likely (99.99%) it's "PHP Script" which is for executing scripts in CLI environment) 3) screenshots please .. or better some screencast. Right now it sounds like you have missed parts of the manual(s) and skipped or misunderstood some of steps.

Comment: @LazyOne, that sounds like it may be the answer.  What file type *should* I create and how do I choose that type in phpstorm?

Comment: `Run | Edit Configurations...` (or via drop down box next to Run/Debug buttons on toolbar), click on green plus icon. Then choose either "PHP Web Application" or "PHP Remote Debug" based on your requirements -- they quite similar. To debug -- I prefer (and recommend, if I have the chance) "zero configuration" approach -- http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm . Also: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/

Comment: @LazyOne OK, did that (Run/Edit Config...) , and it launches the browser ... showing the XAMPP server screen, not my page.  Screen Shot: http://screencast.com/t/TqUaHh9iYHa

Comment: Is the issue that I have to specify the Start URL in the Config for *each* time I start from a different page?
Is there no way to tell phpStorm "hey, ummm... default to starting at the page I specified in the Config". ?

Comment: I then had to specify the Start URL to be the page then it launched that page OK, which lead to the question above this comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Could you please clarify -- what is the problem now? Generally speaking: each run/debug configuration has to have a subject (a file or URL to work with) which is static (i.e. cannot be current file you are working with right now -- it has to be defined in advance).

Comment: If you want to open current file -- you can use "Preview file in..." or "Open in Browser ..." actions (under `View` menu) but 1) you have to have properly configured Deployment entry and it has to be marked as Default for this project and 2) it does not work with "nice" (rewritten) URLs -- it will reflect your directory structure as is.

Comment: Ok, I see how that works now.  Now that I manually set the start URL it works fine.